# web browser screen share - "stop share" handler

Tags: javascript, web, screensharing

Once a screen share is started by "navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()" and confirmed by user, there is a posibility in each browser to stop a screen share (for example Chrome - see pic).
[image]

How to attach a javascript handler on the event, when a screen share is stopped by this browser button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this sample here:
https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/getdisplaymedia/js/main.js#L31

on line 31 an event handler is attached to MediaStreamTrack

```
stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', () => {
    console.log('The user has ended sharing the screen');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oninactive` event.

```
stream.oninactive = function () {
  // Do staff.
}
```

[For more resources.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_media_stream_apis.htm)

Comment: thanks, it's working (but not sure whether "ended" or "oninactive" should be correct answer)